# Parsing link from HTM with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get a link from a page, but it seems not working. I need to catch a singluar link, contaning a keyword, but it seems catching nothing...

I use this code:

```
Element summonerLink = doc.select("a:[href]:contanis(summoner)").first();
            summonerURL = summonerLink.attr("href");
```

I tried to use setText(summonerURL) but it goes blank... (Of course summonerURL is String)

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
 doc.select("a[href*=summoner]")
```

for more info check jsoup [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) look for [attr*=value]

Comment: does the link exists in doc? if it does can you show an example?

Comment: if i do this selector: a[href*=jsoup] on this website it works.